# Best way to write a system of conditions

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, functional-style

Quite simply, I am wondering if there is a cleaner (and more easily altered) way to write a system of conditions for an evaluation. For instance, suppose I have something like (I don't think a real MWE is needed here)

```
FindInstance[a1 && a2 &&...&& an]
```

where each `a` is a conditional expression.

Is there a way to write this as something like the following?

```
Conditions1 = a1 && a2 && a3;
Conditions2 = a4 && a5 &&...&& an;
FindInstance[Conditions1 && Conditions2]
```

Any more practical alternatives are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Because `And` has the attribute [`Flat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html), `And[a, b, And[c, And[d, e]], And[f, g]]` is the same as `And[a,b,c,d,e,f,g`]:

```
And[a, b, And[c, And[d, e]], And[f, g]]
```

> ```
>  a && b && c && d && e && f && g
> ```

```
And[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

> ```
>  a && b && c && d && e && f && g
> ```

Using the example conditions for cvgmt's answer:

```
conditions1 = And[x + y > 0, x y > 0]
```

> ```
> x + y > 0 && x y > 0
> ```

```
conditions2 = And[x > 1, y < 5]
```

> ```
>  x > 1 && y < 5
> ```

```
And[conditions1, conditions2]
```

> x + y > 0 && x y > 0 && x > 1 && y < 5

```
FindInstance[conditions1 && conditions2, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 2, y -> 5/2}}
> ```

**Note:** Re the argument `expr` in `FindInstance[expr, ...]`

[FindInstance >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html):

[image]

and [Reduce >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html):

[image]

So, you can also do

```
FindInstance[{conditions1, conditions2}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 2, y -> 5/2}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
conditions1 = {x + y > 0, x*y > 0};
conditions2 = {x > 1, y < 5};
FindInstance[Join[conditions1, conditions2], {x, y}]
```